# ISBN accept numbers only (python)

Tags: python, numbers, isbn

I have created a code with the help of a few user on stackoverflow. I have found a problem in my code. The problem with my code is that when the user enters the ISBN wrong more than twice then it code up with an error

here's my code:

```
isbn= input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    isbn=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
    continue

else:
    total= 0
   for digit in isbn: total += int(digit)
    calculation=total%11
    digit11=11-calculation
    if digit11==10:
       digit11='X'
    iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
    print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)
```

Comment: I think ISBN numbers can start with 0 therefore they should not be cast to numbers.

Comment: You don't get to ask questions about coursework, and then hide the question.  If you don't want your professor to see it, then don't post it here in the first place.

Comment: Posting your answer in your question isn't going to work either.  You need to learn more about how this site works before you post your next question.    See http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: See also [How does Editing Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `while` loop, the following code tries to convert the input string to `int`.

```
isbn = int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
```

`int` objects has no `isdigit` methods; cause `AttributeError`.

```
>>> isbn = 12345
>>> isbn.isdigit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

`len(int)` causes `TypeError`.

```
>>> len(isbn)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Remove `int(..)` call.

```
isbn = input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that `int` in the while loop. In fact, you want to convert ISBN to number only *after* checking that it is a number, indeed.

Also, you don't need neither the `else` nor the `continue` statements:

```
isbn= input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    isbn=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

total= 0
for i in range(len(isbn)):
    total= int(isbn[i])
calculation=total%11
digit11=11-calculation
if digit11==10:
   digit11='X'
iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)
```

I don't know if the algorithm implemented is correct, but the code above will run.

Comment: you have the best answer. is i possible for you to vote me up so i can vote you up

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer fully working

```
isbn= input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    isbn=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

total= 0
for i in range(len(isbn)):
    total= int(isbn[i])
calculation=total%11
digit11=11-calculation
if digit11==10:
   digit11='X'
iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)
```